# line graph of two variables against time on X-axis such that I have the start date and end date

Tags: python, date, matplotlib, line

How can I draw a line graph of two variables against time on X-axis such that I have the start date and end date and as many dates(quarters) in between as possible without overlaying of the dates.

This is my first ever plot in Python and I am new to Python as such. I have tried every possible suggestion on stackoverlow but couldn't get what I want.

I have a data frame with 4 columns. I want to choose the rows for a particular State and draw a plot of Var 1 and Var 2 against the dates. The date is quarterly data for 10 years.

```
Date            State         Var1      Var2   Var3
0  01-Dec-05  New South Wales  6718023  81.8  5.293757
1  01-Mar-06  New South Wales  6735528  80.8  4.978780
2  01-Jun-06  New South Wales  6742690  82.3  5.288439
3  01-Sep-06  New South Wales  6766133  82.0  5.200780
4  01-Dec-06  New South Wales  6786160  82.7  4.811675
5  01-Mar-07  New South Wales  6815359  81.9  4.957025
6  01-Jun-07  New South Wales  6834156  85.2  4.574077
7  01-Sep-07  New South Wales  6859736  87.3  4.655129
8  01-Dec-07  New South Wales  6883852  89.2  4.647184
9  01-Mar-08  New South Wales  6919907  88.5  4.337943
```

I am plotting

```
plt.plot(mydf[mydf['State'] == 'New South Wales']['Date'], mydf[mydf['State'] == 'New South Wales']['variable1'], '--bD', mydf[mdf['State'] == 'New South Wales']['variable2'], '--bD')
```

I tried this using np.arrange, plot.xticks(length of teh dates, label, rotation), ticker.MultipleLocator and few other things. I couldn't get anything to work.

Also I tried to get a bigger plot that would show all the dates. Not successful either. I want as many dates as possible within the start and end date. In fact month and year would suffice as I have Quarterly data.

The graph looks like this at the moment,

[simple plot with cluttered dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpQ2Q.png)

If I add

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 39, step=2))
```

I get a good graph but the end date is not right.

[plot with step size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28EMt.png)

Would greatly appreciate any advice on helping me with this.

EDIT: I indexed my data frame based on suggestions. The Date and the State column together form an index fort he data frame as the Dates get repeated for each State.

I plotted again using

```
plt.plot(df4[df4['State'] == 'New South Wales']['Var1'], '--bD', df4[df4['State'] == 'New South Wales']['Var2'], '--rD')
```

But now the x-axis is an index and not a Date.

Pls help !!!

Answer (score 0):

For simple 2D plot try this

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel('/home/mrki/np.xls')
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

plt.plot(df['var1'],'r--')
plt.show()
```

It is importan to set Date as index and you can add more variables.

Comment: I indexed the data frame as you advised with Date and State because Dates are duplicated for every state. But I don't get dates on the x-axis now.

Comment: Have you read data into data frame?Can you show us your code?